# DateDiff in PHP causing Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X) in

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to get the difference between 2 dates in PHP.

```
//$tempoAteSaidaEmSegundos = (strtotime($horaSaidaFunc->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'))) - (strtotime($dataC2->format('Y-m-d H:m:s')));

$tempoAteSaidaEmSegundos = date_diff($dataC2, $horaSaidaFunc)->s;
```

The commented line gives me the difference but it's not accurate, so I tried *date_diff* function, which gives me the result I need, but testing the code I noticed that dates with a bigger difference than ~ 1/2 days cause this error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

- 

```
public function horarioUtil(DateTime $dataConclusao, $tempoAdicionar, $horaSaida = 18, $minutoSaida = 0, $horaEntrada = 8, $minutoEntrada = 0)
{
    $dataC = clone $dataConclusao;
    $dataC2 = clone $dataConclusao;
    $dataC3 = clone $dataConclusao;
    $horaSaidaFunc = date_time_set($dataC, $horaSaida, $minutoSaida);
    $dataConclusao->modify("+{$tempoAdicionar} seconds");
    if ($dataConclusao >= $horaSaidaFunc) {
        //$tempoAteSaidaEmSegundos = (strtotime($horaSaidaFunc->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'))) - (strtotime($dataC2->format('Y-m-d H:m:s')));
        $tempoAteSaidaEmSegundos = date_diff($dataC2, $horaSaidaFunc)->s;
        return [
            "util" => false,
            "segDiffSaida" => $tempoAdicionar - $tempoAteSaidaEmSegundos,
            "conclusao" => $dataConclusao,
            "nextDay" => $dataC3->modify("+1 day")
        ];
    } else {
        return [
            "util" => true,
            "conclusao" => $dataConclusao
        ];
    }
}

public function geraDataPrevisaoDeConclusao($prioridadeTempoEmSegundos, $horaEntrada = 8, $minutoEntrada = 0, $horaSaida = 18, $minutoSaida = 0, DateTime $datePosFinalDeSemana = null)
{
    if ($datePosFinalDeSemana != null) {
        $today = $datePosFinalDeSemana;
    } else {
        $today = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
        //$today->modify("+3 day");
    } 

    $bool = $this->horarioUtil($today, $prioridadeTempoEmSegundos, $horaSaida, $minutoSaida);

    if ($bool["util"] === true) {
        // Tempo da prioridade permite a resposta no dia atual. 
        return ($bool["conclusao"]); // Retorna Data de Previsão
    } else {
        // Tempo da prioridade NÃO permite a resposta no dia atual.
        if (!$this->finalDeSemana($bool["nextDay"], false)) { // Verifica se proximo dia é final de semana -> CASE false não é final de semana
            $segundosCalculados = $bool["segDiffSaida"];
            return $this->geraDataPrevisaoDeConclusao($segundosCalculados, $horaEntrada, $minutoEntrada, $horaSaida, $minutoSaida, date_time_set($bool["nextDay"], $horaEntrada, $minutoEntrada));
        } else { //                                                                                  -> CASE true é final de semana
            $segundosCalculados = $bool["segDiffSaida"];
            return $this->geraDataPrevisaoDeConclusao($segundosCalculados, $horaEntrada, $minutoEntrada, $horaSaida, $minutoSaida, date_time_set($bool["nextDay"]->modify("next monday"), $horaEntrada, $minutoEntrada));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that line alone is doing that. Please show us a bit more code around this piece you show us

Comment: Added the whole function

Comment: Can you share more details, like a runnable example that triggers the problem? Without knowing which parameters you use to call that method, its pretty difficult to reproduce the problem

Comment: It is more likely the creation of the array in the return that is causing the issue. but if you are blowing a 512meg memory limit there are probably other issues we cannot see

Comment: Added more code, I get error when I call geraDataPrevisaoDeConclusao() with 50400 seconds. Maybe something with the recursive call?

Comment: Thats a recursive call. My guess you have to look at why you are consuming all your memory, has the recursion gone wrong and is running wild

Comment: So you are consuming 20k each time you make a recursive call, how many times do you expect to have to recurse into this function

Comment: That's weird, because when I run the code with the commented line everything works fine but I get the wrong result, that's why I don't think it's the recursive call, but now I'll check the creation of the array, that's a good guess.

Comment: Oh, i was being dumb. date_diff->s does not return the full difference in seconds. It was returning only the rest of it in seconds, so was returning something like 1~59seconds, causing a non stop recursive calling to stop the calculation. Changed the date diff line to: " $tempoAteSaidaEmSegundos = $horaSaidaFunc->getTimestamp() - $dataC2->getTimestamp();
"